# Is a completely degenerate binary tree worse than a linked list?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, space-complexity

Considering time and space what is worse? A linked list or a completely degenerate binary tree?

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same? A completely degenerate binary tree should basically be a linked list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most that can be said is: a linked list is never worse than a degenerate binary tree. Is it actually better? Probably not so much.

Let's compare:

- **linked list**

```
item -> item -> item -> item -> item -> item -> item ->NUL
```

- **degenerate binary tree**

```
item -> item -> item -> item -> item -> item -> item ->NUL
 \    \    \    \    \    \    \    \    \    \    \
  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL  NUL
```

### Space

Note that the arrows in the previous diagrams are pointers; hence, the memory space occupied by an arrow is the size of a pointer, probably up to 64 bits. The size of an item depends on the item itself, and might go from 8 bits if it's a character up to something huge if it's an object of a complex class with lots of data.

- The size of the linked list is `n * (sizeof(item) + sizeof(ptr))` if the items are contained in the nodes, or `n * (sizeof(item) + 2 * sizeof(ptr))` if the nodes hold pointers to the items.
- The size of the degenerate binary tree is `n * (sizeof(item) + 2 * sizeof(ptr))`, or `n * (sizeof(item) + 3 * sizeof(ptr))`, again depending on whether the nodes contain the items directly or pointers to the items.
  It is pretty reasonable to assume that the same of an item is at least as large as the size of a pointer. More precisely:
- The size of the degenerate binary tree is twice the size of the linked list, if the items are integers using about as much space as pointers;
- The size of the degenerate binary tree is only a negligible factor larger than the size of the linked list, if the items are very large compared to pointers.
  If you are a theorist and only care about *O( )*, then a factor between 1 and 2 won't affect this *O( )* and you can consider that the two are equivalent. If you are a real person in the real world and care about actual used space in memory, then the degenerate binary tree might take up to twice more memory, which might be an issue or not.

### Time

Iterating through the degenerate binary tree is similar to iterating on the linked list, except some time will be lost exploring the dummy leaves. How much time is lost exactly? This depends on the exact algorithm, but it seems reasonable to assume there will be a factor, *negligible* or not. Algorithms using the degenerate binary tree will be slower than the linked list. Again, this doesn't affect the *O( )*, but in the real world this means you might be spending 2μs instead of 1μs, or 2s instead of 1s, or 1h instead of 30min, etc.

Note that one of the things that slows processors the most today is wrongly-guessed conditions. When iterating through a list, you need to test the pointer to the next element at each iteration of the loop, so as to answer the question "are we done yet or is there a next element?". When executing the program with the linked list, in most iterations except the last, the processor will rightly guess "there is a next element" and this is a huge gain of time. When executing the program with the degenerate binary tree, the processor might guess wrong half the time, because half the pointers are NUL and half are not. This might be a huge loss of time.

### Conclusion

It's a good guess that linked lists are not worse than degenerate binary trees, but how much better are they exactly is hard to tell and highly circumstantial. Space is probably not an issue. Time will likely be noticeable, so don't use a degenerate binary tree if you can use a linked list; but if for some reason you need to use a binary tree in most cases, and it happens that in a few cases the tree is degenerate, don't stress over it and don't try to over-optimise by replacing it with a linked list.

Comment: Is the tree REALLY twice the size of the list? You don't have double the nodes, you still have six in both cases, with the tree you only have six other pointers to nothing. I am not really sure the argument holds up. By that logic, a double-linked list is the same also takes up twice the memory of a single linked list but I highly doubt that. Probably language/implementation dependant but I'd expect a *node* to not double in size by adding another pointer to it.

Comment: The overhead of the tree structure is 2 pointers vs 1.

Comment: @VLAZ Depends how large an item is. I can imagine three kinds of nodes: 1) nodes which hold a number directly; 2) nodes which hold some data; 3) nodes which hold a pointer to some data. The exact factor depends on the size of the data and the kind of node. Also please note that I did edit my answer approximately at the same time as you wrote your comment.

Comment: @Stef while the information you provide here is *correct*, I'm not sure it really answers the question. It's tagged with space and time complexity, which usually means that we don't care about the *exact* numbers but the big-O growth rate. And if we are supposed to make a real analysis, then we lack a lot of data. Here you assume two very simple data structures a single linked list and a binary tree. Yet, there are many implementations that might be used and the conclusions here might not apply as the memory footprint might be different. Platform/language might also play a role.